# React-Native 'ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\users\lhlin\package.json''

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

This is first time trying to use React Native using expo and this message appeared

```
PS C:\users\lhlin> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT 
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\users\lhlin\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\users\lhlin\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lhlin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-19T06_10_39_141Z-debug.log
```

I don't Know what is Wrong. Pls Help.

Comment: Please share project structure  ( PS C:\users\lhlin>  What's inside this ) @Aspectx . You need to run npm start inside the project where you create a project using the command.

Comment: nvm i found a solution by just doin npm install in the directory